# Apex SOQL All Distinct Histories of a Field?

Tags: apex, soql, field-history

I am trying to query every state of `Transaction_Property__c` where the field `Status__c` is distinct.

I've tried the following but it only gives me the latest record and not all versions.

```
List<Transaction_Property__c> loans = [
  SELECT
    Id,
    Borrower_First_Name__c,
    Status__c,
    (SELECT NewValue FROM Histories)
  FROM Transaction_Property__c
  WHERE Borrower_Name__c = '0032h00000Je9xcAAB'
];
```

Example of desired record values:

```
<Id>, John, StatusA
<Id>, John, StatusB
<Id>, John, StatusC
```

What I'm basically getting:

```
<Id>, John, StatusC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.debug doesn't show parent or child relationships. Use JSON.serialize, for example, to see the values, or you can collect them manually:

```
Set<String> uniqueValues = new Set<String>();
for(Transaction_Property__c property: loans) {
  for(Transaction_Property__History history: property.histories) {
    uniqueValues.add((String)history.newValue);
  }
}
```

Or, query them from the bottom up:

```
Transaction_Property__History[] histories = [
  select newvalue, parent.borrower_first_name__c, parent.status__c
  from transaction_property__history
  where parent.borrower_name__c = '0032h00000Je9xcAAB'
];
```

Note that this query has the disadvantage of not showing the parent record if there are no history items.

Comment: Is there a way to filter the `NewValue` by _field_? I want to know the _field_ the `NewValue` occurred on so that I can restrict it to only caring about `Status__c` _field_.

Comment: @gpresland Yes, you can filter on Field to find just changes to one or more fields.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to accomplish this. `history` appears to only have the property `newValue`, and there's no intellisense to help me out. I'm expecting a property like `fieldName` for me to use for filtering. Or is this accomplished by modifying the SOQL?

Comment: Figured it out. Had to modify my query to `(SELECT Field, NewValue FROM Histories)` then I could access the _field_ with `history.field`.